# php artisan serve not generating url (localhost:8000) in right directory

Tags: php, laravel-8, laravel-7, laravel-6, laravel-artisan

I completed upgrades from laravel 5 to laravel 8.
But my php artisan serve is not working.
I mean when i type php artisan serve and type enter then we should get an output showing some localhost link.
But for me it is not doing that

```
C:\Users\kr php artisan serve
C:\Users\kr
```

Comment: Any one in the world able to help me???

Comment: It should give you some verbose message why it can't start. Go to `config/app.php` and change `debug` to `true`.

Comment: Is your Laravel perfect really in the location `C:\Users\kr`? Are you getting any output at all, or is it hanging, or is it existing immediately?

Comment: Hi, I set to true in config/app.php. But still not working, after lot of changes in the dependency versions in composer.json file now it changed to  odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified, SQL state IM002 in SQLConnect . But not getting any idea how to over come this

Answer (score 0):

go to the .env file and change localhost to 127.0.0.1

Comment: thanks, its worked for me

Comment: please mark as correct answer